# Creating a Database and User permission in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I am running `mysql` server on my ubuntu machine,

I created a database using the following line of code:

```
CREATE DATABASE Quizzie;
```

Now , I want to grant permission to users in this database, so I used the following line of code.

```
GRANT ALL ON Quizzie.* TO 'user'@'localost' IDENTIFIED BY 'user';
GRANT ALL ON Quizzie.* TO 'user'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'user';
```

But I get following errors:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'Abhilekh'' at line 1
```

Comment: No I haven't created a user

Comment: MySQL 8.0 changed the syntax for creating users and running grants. If you are following instructions written for earlier versions of MySQL, you should read the [current manual on Account Management Statements in MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-management-statements.html).